# Mysql query to show results from between two columns

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i have a mysql database, in which i have two columns Year_from & Year_two.

what i am trying to do is find a way where i can show the dates that are missing as buttons, for example if year from is 2006 and year to is 2008, i of course want to show 2006, **2007** and 2008. is this possible, as there isn't the value of 2007 in the database.

I haven't worked on any code yet as i am not sure if this is possible, or how i would achieve it.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Add a table containing all relevant years

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `range($year_from, $year_to)` to generate a list of all years. Compare that array with the one you got from the database using `array_diff()` and bold the missing ones.

Answer (score 0):

This needs to be done in code.
Basically, you'll read a bunch of records from the database, iterate through an array of years you'd like to show and check (every iteration) if there is a matching record present in the result set.